# Wireshark capturing packets bewteen VMs on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, wireshark

I am trying to get wireshark to capture packets between two Windows 10 vms on an Ubuntu 18.04 host. I first tried using a host-only network with promiscuous mode set to allow all, but wireshark was unable to capture any of the packets. How do I solve this?

Comment: If those VM is in internal network then use Wireshark in any VM.